# Solving a cubic equation using a rotated and scaled equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, polynomials, triangles, roots, cubics

There is this property of a cubic equation with 3 distinct real solutions where you can draw an equilateral triangle above the graph (center lined up with the inflection point), and it can always be rotated and scaled such that the corners line up with the roots, and the leftmost/rightmost points on an inscribed circle line up with the extrema.

[image]

I saw this in a [video by Mathologer about the cubic formula](https://youtu.be/N-KXStupwsc?t=1976) and I was wondering if there was a way to solve this type of cubic using the only the triangle and POI/extrema.

I have looked up methods using trigonometry, but they just use algebraic manipulation with the formula for cos(3θ), no direct geometric relation.

I'm not really sure where to start. I was thinking maybe finding the radius of the inscribed circle and relating that to the length of each side, but I wouldn't know which direction to go to reach the corners. Maybe there is some other approach that I am missing.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "solve [...] using only the triangle and POI/extrema", but ... Suppose the circle has center $K:=(h,k)$ and radius $r$; then x-coords of the triangle's vertices are $x_n:=h+2r\cos(\theta+2\pi n/3)$ for some $\theta$, with $n=0,1,2$. These are the roots of the (monic) cubic function $$\begin{align}y&=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\\ &=x^3-3hx^2+3(h^2-r^2)x-h^3+3hr^2-2r^3\cos3\theta\end{align}$$ So, given such a cubic, the coefficient of $x^2$ tells us $h$; that and the coeff of $x$ tell us $r$; and then the constant term allows us to deduce $\theta$. Does that help?

Comment: How did you find the expression for $x_n$ geometrically? It does look very familiar. This turns up after using the cubic formula when simplifying the complex numbers, the imaginary parts cancel out and you are left with $2r\cos\left(\theta+\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)-\frac{b}{3a}$, where $r$ is the magnitude of the complex conjugates inside the roots and $-\frac{b}{3a}$ is where $h$ would be centered. I just don't understand where this comes from geometrically.

Comment: If the inradius of an equilateral triangle is $r$, then the circumradius is $2r$. (The incenter and circumcenter coincide at the centroid, which is $2/3$rds the distance from vertex to opposite side.) A point at distance $2r$ from $K:=(h,k)$ has coordinates $(h+2r\cos\theta,k+2r\sin\theta)$ for some $\theta$, so that accounts for one vertex. To get the others, add $2\pi/3$ and $4\pi/3$ to $\theta$.

Comment: This does make sense now, thank you. I know complex numbers often have to do with rotation and scaling, so I did think there was a strong parallel here. Now in terms of proving this triangle property holds for all cubics with 3 distinct real solutions, I was thinking of just comparing the result given to the one from the cubic formula, not sure if there's any better way to prove it. Like I think this geometric scenario might have been realized afterwards anyways.

Comment: See Fig. 4 of [this article](https://maa.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00029890.2019.1528814#.YPnkCT1xfIU) of the American Mathematical Monthly Vol. 126, 2019, pages 33-40 :"The Joukowsky maps reveals the cubic equation "

Comment: That article was very interesting an helpful! I didn't initially think about cubics set up as a conformal map, but this reveals so much more insightful information about the source of where the equilateral triangle comes from.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone is going to give a direct answer to close the thread, or if I might prepare one myself and then close it. Probably best to keep that article as a reference though.

Comment: Indeed, in order that this thread is closed, it would be a good thing that you (or I) write a short answer taking into account the AMM article.

Comment: FWIW, here's a write up I made about the roots of a cubic being expressed in terms of a complex hyperbolic angle: https://github.com/awalls-cx18/cubic/blob/master/doc/cubic_hyp.pdf and an accompanying Geogebra sim: https://www.geogebra.org/m/a59xns3b .  Move the "d" slider to see the relation of the complex hyperbolic angle on the left, to the roots of the cubic on the right.